# Objective-C: problem with a simple if x == y || y || y command

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, if-statement

I have a string (containing a month) and would like to check if it is a 'short' month (in terms of the length of the name) or a 'month' name. According to the length of the name I would like to set up its position:

```
    NSString* dateMonth = @"SEPTEMPER";
if (dateMonth == @"MARCH" || @"APRIL" || @"MAY" || @"JUNE" || @"JULY") {

    CGRect calendarFrame = CGRectMake(170+100, 8, 200, 50);
    calendar1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:calendarFrame];
    calendar1.clipsToBounds = true;

} else {

    CGRect calendarFrame = CGRectMake(170,     8, 200, 50);
    calendar1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:calendarFrame];
    calendar1.clipsToBounds = true;

}
```

This case should end up in the ELSE function, but it does not... I end up with the 170+100 position.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code

```
if (dateMonth == @"MARCH" || @"APRIL") {
```

is actually evaluated as

```
if ((dateMonth == @"MARCH") || (@"APRIL")) {
```

And since `@"APRIL"` is not a zero or nil, it's evaluated as `TRUE`.

What can be done

- Step 1 (partly fixed)

  ```
  if ((dateMonth == @"MARCH") || (dateMonth == @"APRIL")) {
  ```
- Step 2 (this already works)
  Use `isEqual` method to compare strings (or any other objects) instead of `==`. `isEqualToString` is also valid, as other people suggest.
- Step 3 (extra mile)
  You can make it much more readable (and simpler) by utilizing set.

  ```
  NSSet *shortMonths = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"MARCH", @"APRIL", @"MAY", nil];
  if ([shortMonths containsObject:@"APRIL"]) {
  ```

Answer (score 2):

`if ([dateMonth isEqualToString:@"MARCH"] || [dateMonth isEqualToString ...`

of maybe you should use

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0];
CGSize size = [dateMonth sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 50)];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this.

```
NSString* dateMonth = @"SEPTEMPER";

NSString* dateMonths = @"MARCH,APRIL,MAY,JUNE,JULY";

if ([dateMonths rangeOfString:dateMonth].location != NSNotFound){

    CGRect calendarFrame = CGRectMake(170+100, 8, 200, 50);
    calendar1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:calendarFrame];
    calendar1.clipsToBounds = true;

} else {

    CGRect calendarFrame = CGRectMake(170,     8, 200, 50);
    calendar1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:calendarFrame];
    calendar1.clipsToBounds = true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't write code in this way this is not right syntax.

```
if (dateMonth == @"MARCH" || @"APRIL" || @"MAY" || @"JUNE" || @"JULY") 
if (dateMonth == @"MARCH" || dateMonth  == @"APRIL" || dateMonth  == @"MAY" || dateMonth  == @"JUNE" || dateMonth  ==@"JULY")
```

The right solution for this problem is follow ...

```
NSString* dateMonth = @"SEPTEMPER";
    if ([dateMonth isEqualToString:@"MARCH"] || [dateMonth isEqualToString:@"APRIL"] || [dateMonth isEqualToString:@"MAY"] || [dateMonth isEqualToString:@"JUNE"] || [dateMonth isEqualToString:@"JULY"]) {

    CGRect calendarFrame = CGRectMake(170+100, 8, 200, 50);
    calendar1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:calendarFrame];
    calendar1.clipsToBounds = true;

} else {

    CGRect calendarFrame = CGRectMake(170,     8, 200, 50);
    calendar1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:calendarFrame];
    calendar1.clipsToBounds = true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString* dateMonth = @"SEPTEMPER";

if ([dateMonth isEqualToString:@"MARCH"] || [dateMonth isEqualToString:@"APRIL"] || [dateMonth isEqualToString:@"MAY"] || [dateMonth isEqualToString:@"JUNE"] || [dateMonth isEqualToString:@"JULY"]) {
CGRect calendarFrame = CGRectMake(170+100, 8, 200, 50);
calendar1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:calendarFrame];
calendar1.clipsToBounds = true;
} 
else
{
CGRect calendarFrame = CGRectMake(170,     8, 200, 50);
calendar1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:calendarFrame];
calendar1.clipsToBounds = true;
}
```

try this. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Your logical operator inside the if statement is incorrect for your desired operation.

What you should write is something like:

`if([dateMonth isEqualToString:@"MARCH"] || [dateMonth isEqualToString:@"APRIL"] || ...)`

Your original expression inside the `if()` statement would have caused the code to execute every time because part of the expression (for example @"APRIL" || @"MAY") would result in a boolean TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Use either the `isEqualToString:` or `compare:`  methods of `NSString`.

Answer (score -2):

Use proper comparison syntax. It should be like :-

```
 NSString* dateMonth = @"SEPTEMPER";

if (dateMonth == @"MARCH" || dateMonth == @"APRIL" || dateMonth == @"MAY" || dateMonth == @"JUNE" || dateMonth == @"JULY")

{
    CGRect calendarFrame = CGRectMake(170+100, 8, 200, 50);
    calendar1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:calendarFrame];
    calendar1.clipsToBounds = true;

} else {

    CGRect calendarFrame = CGRectMake(170,     8, 200, 50);
    calendar1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:calendarFrame];
    calendar1.clipsToBounds = true;

}
```

Comment: This is not working code !!! if (dateMonth == @"MARCH" || dateMonth == @"APRIL" || dateMonth == @"MAY" || dateMonth == @"JUNE" || dateMonth == @"JULY") you cant write in this way !!!